# nodename nor servname provided, or not known in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

When I run my JMeter scripts I get this error to a particular URL (site B) JMeter is trying to access.

> nodename nor servname provided, or not known

For this URL, the access control allow origin has been set "site A". I was seeing this in response.

Is this the reason, it is failing from JMeter. Should this call be done only from "Site A". Is their any settings that we can pass from in the headers?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: need more details